# Cold temperatures cause finger resistance on  iPad screen

Tags: ipad, touchscreen, temperature

I have an issue that I've been experiencing: semi-cold fingers, iPad, and/or room make for a very stubborn drawing experience (I'm an artist that uses the iPad).

I'm talking indoors, and it doesn't have to be that cold to trigger the problem: even slightly below normal room temperature.

There's a real resistance that happens. My fingers don't seamlessly glide around. Slows me down like heck.

I can't figure out how to fix it (I can rub my fingers quickly on my pants to create friction for a very quick fix).

Could this be a humidity or a room pressure thing?

It's not about too little oil on one's fingers or if the glass is clean. I can't find anything online, although I've talked to some folks who say they sometimes have this problem with their smartphones.

Anyone know anything about this; and, more importantly, how to circumvent it in a reasonable way?

Comment: Most random comment ever: I have a similar problem if I use my MacBook's trackpad if I have a tiny bit of banana residue on my fingers. Connection? Probably not. But I couldn't help sharing...

Comment: I find sometimes if I've been playing games on my iPhone for a while their starts to be an increase in resistance; also not sure how to solve this. I find wiping the screen helps, but guess this is different from being cold...

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar issues, and my guess has been that it's due to poor circulation when the temperature drops.

The solutions I've come up with are to buy either:

- a stylus
- a pair of gloves with conductive tips ([like these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003M8H1JA))
- something like the [GloveTips 3-Piece Touchscreen Texting Glove Tips](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004BBDI58) (which you can apply to an existing pair of gloves).

Comment: Thanks Dori. In the interim I've actually found it to be a combination of cold glass/ screen mixed with moisture. Heating it up ( there are many ways/ things to do this safely) seems to do the trick....

Answer (score 0):

Use some hand lotion or wash your hands and then try again. Dry fingers may cause that.

Answer (score 0):

A lot people find anti-glare screen protectors do the trick! They're slightly textured.